# Java Generic how to change parameterized subclass

Tags: java, generics

I have such structure:

```
public class Record{}
public class ParsedRecord extends Record {}
public class RecordsList extends ParsedRecord {}

public abstract class Processor<T extends Record >{ private BlockingQueue<T> queue;}

public class Dispatcher extends Processor<ParsedRecord> {

    List<ParsedRecord> list;

    public Dispatcher() {
    }

    public void process(ParsedRecord record){
      //blabla
    }
  }
```

I want to use Dispatcher class with parameters that are ParsedRecord or any type that extends from ParsedRecord class.

Could some please help me to understand how to properly change Dispatcher class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be as simple as changing your class definition to:

```
public class <T extends ParsedRecord> Dispatcher extends AbstractProcessor<T> {
```

and then: use that `T` as type for your list, or for the parameter given to `process()`.

But the real answer here is: **study** the [concept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Don't try to go with trial and error.

Comment: I've try this variant before but get errors in Dispatcher subclasses  and wasn't sure about that.After your response I fixed this. Thanks. I promise that I will learn generics thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a `Processor` class but you extend `AbstractProcessor`.
You have probably do a naming mistake in the question.

So I suppose you have only an `AbstractProcessor` class to give a concrete answer.

In your case, if you want related the type declaration of the class with the parameter of the method, you have to declare the method in the parent class first and specify the parameter of it with the declared type :

```
public abstract void process(T record){
```

You would have a parent class :

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessor<T extends Record >{
    ...
    public abstract void process(T record);
   ...
}
```

And in the subclass you get this symmetric declaration :

```
public class Dispatcher extends AbstractProcessor<ParsedRecord> {    
    ...

    public void process(ParsedRecord record){
      //blabla
    }
}
```

Comment: I've change original names for classes) And forgot one

Comment: You got my vote here; as you took the time to ask about the inconsistencies in the question; which helped improving that thing in the end!

Comment: As usually you are fair :)